# Php DOMDocument Htmlentities problem

Tags: php, domdocument

I use DOMDocument. My code here.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$textNode = $dom->createTextNode('<input type="text" name="lastName" />');
$dom->appendChild($textNode);
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
&lt;input type="text" name="lastName" /&gt;
```

I want to this output

```
<input type="text" name="lastName" />
```

How can i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something that actually parses the xml data instead of treating it as "plain" text. DOMDocumentFragment and [DOMDocumentFragment::appendXML()](http://docs.php.net/domdocumentfragment.appendxml) can do that.
E.g.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadhtml('<html><head><title>...</title></head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="lalala">
      <div id="formcontrols">
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="submit" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>');

// find the parent node of the new xml fragement
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$parent = $xpath->query('//div[@id="formcontrols"]');
// should test this first
$parent = $parent->item(0);

$fragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML('<input type="text" name="lastName" />');
$parent->appendChild($fragment);

echo $doc->savehtml();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `createTextNode` with `createElement`. Text nodes are for *text* :)

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$textNode = $dom->createElement('input');
$textNode->setAttribute('type', 'text');
$textNode->setAttribute('name', 'lastName');
$dom->appendChild($textNode);
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Yes i know. My code is example. But i want to add html code in text node.

Comment: So? I just tested the code and it outputs what you are asking for.

Comment: Edited my question. I just want to DOMDocument don't convert htmlentities. Sorry my English is bad.

Comment: @scopus: what Coronatus had put is correct, can you explain how it's not what you are asking?

Comment: plus 1 for opening my eyes with: "Text nodes are for text"

Answer (score 1):

look at the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createtextnode.php) one of the first things is says

"A quick note to anyone who is using character entities (e.g. ©) in this, and finding them automatically escaped. The correct thing to do here is to use the createEntityReference method (e.g. createEntityReference("copy");), and then appendChild this entity between text nodes. "